# how to pluck only date in php laravel query from timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel

using this query

```
 $orders = Order::has('get_ot_creater')
                        ->with('seller')
                        ->where('approve_date',"!=",NULL)
                        ->pluck('approve_date')->toArray();
```

I am getting array of `approve_date` with i want to remove time how i can get only dates?

my output is

```
  0 => "2021-03-26 19:32:00"
  1 => "2021-03-24 20:06:00"
  3 => "2021-03-22 13:02:00"
  26 => "2021-03-29 00:33:00"
  42 => "2021-03-25 15:50:00"
```

i want only dates like `2021-03-25`

Comment: what your current output, and what the output you want?

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: This may help you : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map

Comment: Hope this will work `->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(approve_date), "%Y-%m-%d") as approve_date'))->pluck('approve_date')->toArray();` add `use DB;` on the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map over the orders:

```php
$orders = Order::has('get_ot_creater')
                        ->with('seller')
                        ->where('approve_date',"!=",NULL)
                        ->pluck('approve_date'); // Note: toArray is removed

$orders = $orders->map(function ($order) {
    return substr($order, 0, 10); // Return only the first ten characters.
});
```

Comment: Or use proper date formatting... If `approve_date` is a Carbon instance (via `protected $dates = ['approve_date'];` on the `Order.php` Model), you could do `return $order->approve_date->format('Y-m-d');`, or, it's not, `return Carbon::parse($order->approve_date')->format('Y-m-d');`. I'd try to avoid string manipulation on Dates if possible. This works, but it feels wrong.